# Trigger Menu to close itself after toggling?

Tags: jquery, menu

So, I am currently working on a portfolio website right now and I have some little problems with my menu/nav.

I have some anchors and I have smoothScroll. js, that it looks a bit nicer. But the problem here is, that the menu doesn't close itself after clicking a tag.

I am an absolute noob at js and it would be very nice to get some help :)
I already tried to do this myself, but I only hide the whole menu section ^^'

Here is my script and html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#not").click(function() {
    $("#not-sub-nav").toggle(200);
    $("#main-menu").hide(500);
  });
  $(".sub-back").click(function() {
    $("#not-sub-nav").hide(200);
  });
  $("#menu-btn").click(function() {
    $("#haff-menu").toggleClass("showHalfMenu");
    $("#main-menu").toggle();
  });
});



<section class="showHalfMenu" id="haff-menu">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--=======SLID-NAV 1============-->
            <section id="nav-1">
                <nav id="main-nav">
                    <h2 class="title"><a href="javascript:;">
               <span class="menu-icon pull-right" id="menu-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" id="chang-menu-icon"></i></span></a></h2>
                    <ul class="ul" id="main-menu">
                        <li id="#">
                            <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">
                                <i class="fa fa-user icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>about
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="#">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-image icon"></i>projects
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="#">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap icon"></i>experience
                            </a>
                        </li>                       
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-address-card icon"></i>contact
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </section>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: please add your html

Comment: Your html doesn't contain any `not` ID or `not-sub-nav` ID or `sub-back` ID or `not-sub-nav` ID ! If you can create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ with your html/css/JS it would be easier to hep. Because here, your first 2 JS functions are targetting nothing !

Comment: I tried, but I dont know if it was the right way :)  @LebCit http://jsfiddle.net/uduotraz/embed/